# Does Patch 10752 undo 10570v2?

Tags: patches, magento-1.9.3.8

Patch 10570v2 no longer cause inability of customers to complete checkout when trying to register during checkout. It is working fine at my 1.9.3.8 store.

When i apply Patch 10752, looks like it undo Patch 10570v2. I can see files changes in Git. Result is the inability of customers to complete checkout when trying to register during checkout again.

Is there any way to apply 10752 without lost 10570v2?